# Photo files: time groups to folders?

Tags: file-management, photography

I have more than 10000 of photos shot with digital camera in a travel, in two-week period.

I need software to group photos by EXIF timestamp into folders, in tiered way: days, museums/landmarks/excursions, individual halls, panoramas, drive-by bursts for a single object.

The software must be not fully automatic, but manually adjustable - some shots are not belonging to any groups, some groups have time gaps in them as i was waiting for some obstacle (bus, other tourist, museum staff) to move away from my sight.

(I already have self-written full-auto script and i am dissatisfied with it - only good for short occasional groups during the day, not hard museum/landmark/excursion running.)

It must not be a "year-month-day" utility - a panorama shot across millenium midnight is still one group ;)

I envision it as zoomable timeline, like video editor, with photos as thin lines on it, and movable selection brackets to designate some time interval as a group and move it to folder.

Comment: Which OS & Price Range?